# VBasic array of labels, name auto settings?

Tags: arrays, label, basic

greets,

I'm trying to create multiple labels as an array but so far nothing works.

e.g. I took this code and put it into Form1_Load, it works and creates one label at run time:

```
    Dim vulabel1 As New Label()
    vulabel1.Size = New Size(100, 20)
    vulabel1.Location = New Point(25, 25)
    vulabel1.Name = "textBox1"
    Me.Controls.Add(vulabel1)
    vulabel1.Text = "vu label 1"
```

When I change it to a for loop it ceases to work:

```
    Dim vulabel() As Label
    For n As Byte = 0 To 2
        vulabel(n).Size = New Size(100, 10)
        vulabel(n).Location = New Point(n * 10, n * 10)
        vulabel(n).Name = "label " & n.ToString
        Me.Controls.Add(vulabel(n))
    Next
```

I thought this should place two labels on the Form1 at runtime.

The reason I need a quick way to create labels is that I need a matrix of 8x8 labels. At least if I could change the default label name so e.g. I would create a label and change the name to vu_label1, copy and then paste other labels named vu_label2, vu_label3, unfortunately Visual Studio keeps changing the label name back to Label1 when I do copy and paste.

Another thing is that you can't declare an array element as the name of a label, e.g. vu_level(1).

thanks for any input

Comment: You just forgot instanciation ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the maximum index when declaring an array. Based on the `For` loop, looks like the maximum index is 2, so this is how you declare the array

```
Dim vulabel(2) As Label
```

The next step is creating a new instance of `Label` at each iteration as below

```
vulabel(n) = New Label()
```

Here's the complete modified code

```
Dim vulabel(2) As Label
For n As Byte = 0 To 2
    vulabel(n) = New Label()        
    vulabel(n).Size = New Size(100, 10)
    vulabel(n).Location = New Point(n * 10, n * 10)
    vulabel(n).Name = "label" & n.ToString
    Me.Controls.Add(vulabel(n))
Next
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I do have another question. Is there a way to access these created labels by their names at run time? i.e. not by calling vulabel(n) but rather label 0, or label 1? If I try to do that, Visual Studio gives me an error, since these labels are not declared.

Comment: Try to remove the space from the `Name` property. By the way, are you using vb.net?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community.

changing the name won't work, I guess because the labels are created at run-time. So e.g. if I had a button with this sub:
     


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        label1.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
    End Sub
   ---- It won't work.     

p.s. how can I post answers with code formating?